# Adding bootstrap in Symfony 4

Tags: php, webpack, symfony4

In my Symfony 4 project, I try to add bootstrap as an import after

```
yarn add bootstrap --dev
```

As I follow documentation, I tried to import bootstrap as follows:

```
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

When I run **yarn encore dev**, it says module not found.

Than I tried this:

```
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";
```

The output is:

```
Syntax Error: ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './alert' in 'C:\Users\tolga\GIT\artifex\node_modules\bootstrap\scss'
```

What am I missing? alert.scss is there but it cannot find module. What should I try?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems I somehow solved the problem. First of all the import directory is this:

```
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap";
```

I don't know why tilde didn't work. Adding sass-loader didn't help.

Answer (score 3):

Old subject but the solution is to change the extension of file `app.css` to `app.scss`.

Comment: This solution works for me, but by default webpack-encore does not have support for sass, it should be installed and enabled in webpack.config.js